# ng-bind-html-unsafe not working

Tags: angularjs

I have upgraded the angular version from 1.0.8 to 1.4.0.

I have used `ng-bind-html-unsafe="value | noHTML | newlines"` to wrap down a string. This is not working since the new version.

I tried using the following solution, but still not working .

```
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });
```

and

```
ng-bind-html-unsafe="value | unsafe | noHTML | newlines"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Angular 1.2.X `ng-bind-html-unsafe` has been deprecated, do use `ng-bind-html`

```
ng-bind-html="value | unsafe | noHTML | newlines"
```

Comment: Tried this. But not working. In this case `filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; })` is required?  Angular Version is 1.4.0

Comment: @ep have you included `ngSanitize` module in you app dependency?

Comment: No. I have'nt. Let me try that.

Comment: It is working for `ng-bind-html="value | unsafe"` but not for `ng-bind-html="value | unsafe | noHTML | newlines"`.

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj. I got it working now. I'am accepting this answer as it helped me to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Pankaj Parkar:

I got it resolved now, I need to filter all. ie., `to_trusted`, `noHTML` and `newlines`. And also we need to get the actual value from `$sce.getTrustedHtml(object)`

```
.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    }
}]).filter('noHTML', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        var str = $sce.getTrustedHtml(text);
        str = str
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;');
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(str);
    }
}]).filter('newlines', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        var str = $sce.getTrustedHtml(text);
        str =  str.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(str);
    }
}])
```

and

```
ng-bind-html="value| to_trusted | noHTML | newlines"
```